# Blocking drop database command

Tags: mysql

I created a MySQL database and created a new user dedicated to that database with all permissions. The new user then proceeded of dropping the database in addition to all tables. I need to block that user from being allowed to drop the database, but allow him to drop anything else.

My question is: is there a server level trigger in MySQL similar to MSSql, or is there another method to do this?

Comment: Please login as that user and run `SHOW GRANTS;` (hide the password)

Comment: Use GRANT function: 
http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/788/HOWTO%3A+GRANT+privileges+in+MySQL#dv

Comment: Maybe you can use revoke (if you've already granted permissions):`REVOKE DROP ON...`
for more info see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/revoke.html

Comment: thanks :) yep, just for the example I wrote Select. I forgot for a moment he asked for drop :)

Comment: You should live by the <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege">Principle of Least Privilege</a> - when you create a user only give them the privileges they absolutely must have. Using a tool like PHPMyAdmin might make it easier for you to see what permissions a user has.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps you want to remove the DROP privilege at the global user level

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET drop_priv = 'N' WHERE user='...' AND host='...' and db='...';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Something to keep in mind: The [**DROP**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_drop) privilege encompasses databases, table, and views. Unfortunately, `DROP DATABASE` and `DROP TABLE` fall under the same privilege scope.

For example

I create a user called kumar and a database called kumar

```
mysql> create database kumar;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> grant all on kumar.* to kumar@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> use kumar
Database changed
mysql> create table rolando (a int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)
```

I logged into mysql as kumar and dropped the database kumar

```
mysql> drop database kumar;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)
```

So, I recreated it as a SUPER user. I also create a database kumar2

```
mysql> create database kumar;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use kumar
Database changed
mysql> create table rolando (a int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> create database kumar2;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I tried to drop kumar2

```
mysql> show grants for kumar@'%';
+--------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for kumar@%                               |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'kumar'@'%'                |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `kumar`.* TO 'kumar'@'%' |
+--------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select user(),current_user();
+-----------------+----------------+
| user()          | current_user() |
+-----------------+----------------+
| kumar@localhost | kumar@%        |
+-----------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> drop database kumar2;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'kumar'@'%' to database 'kumar2'
mysql>
```

Thus, kumar@'%' can only drop the kumar database. kumar@'%' cannot drop any other database.

## CONCLUSION

The user kumar@'%' can drop the following:

- All Views in the kumar database
- All Tables in the kumar database
- The kumar database itself

You can either allow all three or restrict all three fro this user's access to the kumar database.

Comment: Hi if DROP DATABASE and DROP TABLE fall under the same privilege scope . In my case  i have to give DROP TABLE permission to that  user and not DROP DATABASE  , so i can say there is noway in mysql to do this to my client?

Comment: Thanks for your time and stuff , and the last thing  in your example can  you make kumar user can drop all tables in Kumar database and also he should NOT ABEL to drop kumar database

Comment: Sadly, the answer to that is no. That is what I meant by privilege scope. Databases, tables, and views in `mysql.db` have the same privilege scope on the `drop_priv` column.

Comment: this doesn't work in mariadb 10.5 as the user mysql table is now a view?

Answer (score 4):

Do not give your user ALL permissions on the databases and/or server. Use the GRANT permissions on your databases, servers, and tables independently.

Mysql "permissions" : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-database-privileges

For example :

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON mydb.* TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
GRANT ALL ON mydb.mytbl TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```